# Подскажите механизм работы хеш-функции

Tags: java

Не могу разобраться в работе хеш-функции. Не могли вы подсказать основные принципы?

```
int h =hash
if (h == 0 && value.length > 0 ) {
    char val[] = value;
    for (int i = 0; i < value.length; i++) {
        h = 31 * h + val[i];
    }
    hash = h;
}
return h;
```

Открыл этод метод, но чувствую, что не то.

Comment: Покажите что у Вас не получилось

Comment: "Напишіть програмні
реалізації двох хеш-функцій для відкритого хешування." - не могу выполнить это задание

Comment: Вы можете просто открыть, например, реализацию метода hash() в String

Comment: @kek, общие принципы: [Хеширование](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Хеширование).